# subset of $(0,\infty)$ is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

Let $\Omega \subset (0,\infty)$ an unbounded open set. Consider the set

$\Sigma = \{x \in (0,\infty): nx \in \Omega$ for infinitely many $n\}$

Show that $\Sigma$ is dense in $(0, \infty)$.

I tried to use Baire's Lemma: if $Kat(A)$ = 1 then $Kat(A^c) = 2$ and $A^c$ is dense. where $Kat(A)$ is the Baire category of the set.

In this case I would have to prove that $Kat(\Sigma^c) = 1$
with $\Sigma^c = \{x \in (0,\infty): nx \in \Omega$ for only finitely many $n\}$.

My problem here is how I can find nowhere dense sets $A_j$ such that their union equals $\Sigma^c$.

How can I find them? or is there a simpler way to solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $\Sigma=\bigcap_m \Sigma_m$, where $\Sigma_m=\bigcup_{n\geq m} \Omega/n$. Each $\Sigma_m$ is open dense. To show density, notice that if $I$ is any open interval in $(0,\infty)$, then the set $\bigcup_{n\geq m} nI$ contains a set of the form $(x,\infty)$.